# Creating svg item on Map Canvas in QGIS API?

Tags: qgis, c++, svg, graphics

I'm working on a project with QGIS-2.4.0 API using C++. I need to load some svg files to the application for displaying as symbols. QGIS API has a class named `QgsMapCanvasItem`, which is an abstract class for items that can be placed on the map canvas. However, there are no subclasses related to svg symbol. So I created an object using `QGraphicsSvgItem` from Qt, here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);

QgsMapCanvas * mypMapCanvas = new QgsMapCanvas(0, 0);
mypMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
mypMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(255, 255, 255));
mypMapCanvas->freeze(false);
mypMapCanvas->setVisible(true);
mypMapCanvas->refresh();

QGraphicsScene *s = mypMapCanvas->scene();
QString fileName = "D:\\qgis\\svg\\symbol\\poi_tower_communications.svg";
QGraphicsSvgItem *m_svgItem = new QGraphicsSvgItem(fileName);

m_svgItem->setScale(0.1);
s->addItem(m_svgItem);

return app.exec();
}
```

But something is wrong, when I click the Minimize button or close button, a debug error occurs, the picture is the debug error.

[image: the debug error]

I know the concepts of Qt Graphics view, scene, item. `QgsMapCanvas` is derived from `QGraphicsView`, `QgsMapCanvasItem` is derived from `QGraphicsItem`, but I couldn't find out which class is derived from `QGraphicsScene`?